# How to check if FileBufferingReadStream is empty?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have net core app, at start of my pipeline I have buffering enabled:

```
builder.Use((Func<HttpContext, Func<Task>, Task>) ((context, next) =>
      {
        context.Request.EnableBuffering(1048576);
        return next();
      }))
```

then I want to compute hash of the request body, and I need to check if it is empty. `EnableBuffering` changes underlying stream to `FileBufferingReadStream` which has `.Length` of 0. When I try to read the stream using `ReadAsync`, there are bytes inside.

What is correct way to check if the request body is empty in such case? Should I attempt to read 1 byte and check if it returns something?

Comment: `await next()` and check the body length of `context.Response` ?

Comment: @RamenTurismo sorry I had typo - I want to check if request is empty, not body. Sorry for that :(

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to check whether the `HTTP Context.Request.Body Stream` is empty, or HTTP request itself is empty, in both cases you could check in following ways:

**When Context.Request.Body stream is empty:**

```cs
        builder.Use((Func<HttpContext, Func<Task>, Task>)((context, next) =>
                    {
                    HttpRequest request = context.Request;context.Request.EnableBuffering(1048576);
                    var buffer = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(request.ContentLength)];
                    await request.Body.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    string requestBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
                    if(requestBody != null)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("Request Body Is not Null");
                        
                    }

                        return next();
                    }));
```

You can get the [official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.length?view=net-6.0#system-io-stream-length).

**When HttpRequest is empty:**

```cs
        builder.Use((Func<HttpContext, Func<Task>, Task>)((context, next) =>
                    {
                        HttpRequest request = context.Request;

                        if (request.ContentLength > 0)
                        {
                            context.Request.EnableBuffering(1048576);
                        }

                        return next();
                    }));
```

You can get more information from the [official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.contentlength?view=netframework-4.8#system-web-httprequest-contentlength).

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: `context.Request.Body.Length` is unknown, because it is streamed asynchronously

Comment: After `context.Request.EnableBuffering(1048576);` body will be replaced with `FileBufferingReadStream`, which shows length of 0, but it's updated to real value after first rread

Comment: So what's else your expectation is could you please explain a bit more ?

Comment: Your answer does not work because underlying stream does not provide length:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/auuSGV

Answer about ContentLength does not work because this header is optional.

Comment: If you want to get `ConentLength` then you should try like this `HttpRequest request = context.Request;
    request.EnableBuffering(1048576);
    request.ContentLength`. You can check this [`answer here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71147818/cannot-get-basic-request-response-in-net-5-web-site-to-work/71153719#71153719)

Comment: This does not work, content length is null, because it's just value from custom header, please see https://dotnetfiddle.net/AzBO46