# Cannot get basic request/response in .NET 5 web site to work

Tags: asp.net-core

*Expanding the basic Hello World code I am trying to read a form and respond with a web
page without using any of the Microsoft frameworks (e.g., no MVC).  I cannot process the
incoming request.  What am I missing?  Code:*

```
// modified code in Hello World startup.cs:

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
            {
                HttpRequest request = context.Request;
                request.EnableBuffering();   //<-- add to try to make it work
                string message = "Unknown";
                try
                {
                    var reader = request.BodyReader;
                    await reader.ReadAsync();   //<-- add to try to make it work
                    message = "Content type: " + (request.ContentType == null ? "Null" : request.ContentType) + "<br>" +
                        "Request size: " + (request.ContentLength == null ? "Null" : request.ContentLength.ToString());
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    message = "Error: " + e.Message;
                }
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(page(message));
            });
        });
    }

    public string page(string message)
    {
        return
            @"<html xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"">
            <meta httm-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' />
            <meta http-equiv=""expires"" content=""0"" />
            <title>
            TANCS TEST(PRODUCITON DATA)
            </title >
            <body>
            <form>
            Enter a value: <input type=""text"" id=""value"" width=20 value=""xyz"">
            <input id=""Save"" type=""submit"">
            </form>
            " + message + @"
            </body>
            </html>";
    }
```

Comment: You say it doesn't work, but you don't say how. Are you getting an error message? What's happening?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, if you think my answer is correct you could accept the answer  by right clicking on left check mark beside your question [you could have a look here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow)
[How to accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As you haven't shared the full `Configure method` in `Startup.cs` file
> so its not clear how you are trying the code. Additionally, you didn't
> shared what exactly not working and blocking you are having with.

However, if you would like to make your shared code working you should implement that in following manner:

***`Startup.cs file:`***

```cs
public class Startup
        {
            public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
            {
                Configuration = configuration;
            }
    
            public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    
            // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
            public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
    
                services.AddControllers();
                services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
                {
                    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Dotnet5App", Version = "v1" });
                });
            }
    
            // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
            {
                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                    //app.UseSwagger();
                   // app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Dotnet5App v1"));
                }
    
                app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    
                app.UseAuthorization();
    
                app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                {
                    endpoints.MapControllers();
                    endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
                    {
                        HttpRequest request = context.Request;
                        request.EnableBuffering();   //<-- add to try to make it work
                        string message = "Unknown";
                        try
                        {
                            var reader = request.BodyReader;
                            await reader.ReadAsync();   //<-- add to try to make it work
                            message = "Content type: " + (request.ContentType == null ? "Null" : request.ContentType) + "<br>" +
                                "Request size: " + (request.ContentLength == null ? "Null" : request.ContentLength.ToString());
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            message = "Error: " + e.Message;
                        }
                        await context.Response.WriteAsync(page(message));
                    });
                    
                    endpoints.MapPost("/", async context =>
                    {
                        HttpRequest request = context.Request;
                        //request.Query["query"].ToString()
                        request.EnableBuffering();   //<-- add to try to make it work
                        string message = "Unknown";
                        try
                        {
                            var reader = request.BodyReader;
                            await reader.ReadAsync();   //<-- add to try to make it work
                            message = "Content type: " + (request.ContentType == null ? "Null" : request.ContentType) + "<br>" +
                                "Request size: " + (request.ContentLength == null ? "Null" : request.ContentLength.ToString());
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            message = "Error: " + e.Message;
                        }
                        await context.Response.WriteAsync(page(message));
                    });
                });
            }
            public string page(string message)
            {
                return
                    @"<html xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"">
                <meta httm-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' />
                <meta http-equiv=""expires"" content=""0"" />
                <title>
                TANCS TEST(PRODUCITON DATA)
                </title >
                <body>
                <form method=""post"">
                Enter a value: <input type=""text"" id="" value"" name=""query"" width=20 value=""xyz"">
                <input id=""Save"" type=""submit"">
                </form>
                " + message + @"
                </body>
                </html>";
            }
        }
```

> ***`Note:`***
> You may have already noticed that I have added one additional `MapPost` because when if you wanted to submit value using `MapGet` by default there will be no `content type` as its query string. So you need to add `MapPost` method for handeling `submit` action. Another point is `method=""post""` because you are submitting `post` request so you need to add this `method=""post""` attribute on your `form` request. Finally if you want to get the `request size` you have to set `name=""query""` on your form as you can see on my code.

> ***`Additionl point is`***, Comment the `app.UseSwagger();` and `app.UseSwaggerUI` so that
> `UseSwaggerUI` will not be prompted on `launch page` instead it will
> launch `page method` which containing the `HTML` file you wanted to
> display.

If you want to develop it further steps you can also check this [`official document`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/min-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-5.0#add-the-api-code) here as well.

***`launchSettings.json:`***

> When you have created new `dotnet5` project by default it will added
> `swagger` on `launchUrl` which can see on `launchSettings.json` so
> here you should modify the `application launchUrl` as the port you
> want for example `https://localhost:44363` instead of `swagger`

***`Output:`***

After implementing above modification run your project and you should get output as bellow:

[image]

> This is the output of your code so far you have shared with us. This is how you can get the `Content type` and `Request size` using the `minimal web API` You can get more details in our [`official document here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/route-to-code?view=aspnetcore-5.0#write-json-response)

Hope above steps guided you accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much (to Md Farid Uddin Kiron).  Your code, with just a few changes, sends out pages, receives requests, and parses out the form variables.  It is fully working.  I cannot thank you enough.

Here is the full code I now have running:

Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace WebSite
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace WebSite
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllers();
            object p = services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Dotnet5App", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseRouting();   // added, JDM
                //app.UseSwagger();
                // app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Dotnet5App v1"));
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
                {
                    HttpRequest request = context.Request;
                    request.EnableBuffering();   //<-- add to try to make it work
                    string message = "Unknown";
                    try
                    {
                        var reader = new StreamReader(request.Body);
                        string result = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                        message = "Content type: " + (request.ContentType == null ? "Null" : request.ContentType) + "<br>" +
                            "Request size: " + (request.ContentLength == null ? "Null" : request.ContentLength.ToString());
                     }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        message = "Error: " + e.Message;
                    }
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync(page(message, null));
                });

                endpoints.MapPost("/", async context =>
                {
                    HttpRequest request = context.Request;
                    request.EnableBuffering();   //<-- add to try to make it work
                    string message = "Unknown";
                    Dictionary<string, string> formVariables = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    try
                    {
                        var reader = new StreamReader(request.Body);
                        string body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                        formVariables = getFormVariables(body);
                        StringBuilder display = new StringBuilder("");
                        foreach (string key in formVariables.Keys)
                        {
                            display.Append(", " + key + " = " + formVariables[key]);
                        }
                        message = "Content type: " + (request.ContentType == null ? "Null" : request.ContentType) + "<br>" +
                            "Request size: " + (request.ContentLength == null ? "Null" : request.ContentLength.ToString()) + "<br>" +
                            "Form Variables: " + display.ToString().Substring(2);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        message = "Error: " + e.Message;
                    }
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync(page(message, formVariables));
                });
            });
        }
        string page(string message, Dictionary<string, string> formValues)
        {
            return
                @"<html xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"">
                <meta httm-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' />
                <meta http-equiv=""expires"" content=""0"" />
                <title>
                TANCS TEST(PRODUCITON DATA)
                </title >
                <body>
                <form method=""post"">
                Enter a value: <input type=""text"" id="" value"" name=""query1"" width=20 value=""" + FormValue(formValues, "query1") + @""">
                Enter a value: <input type=""text"" id="" value"" name=""query2"" width=20 value=""" + FormValue(formValues, "query2") + @"""><br>
                <input id=""Save"" type=""submit"">
                </form>
                " + message + @"
                </body>
                </html>";
        }

        public string FormValue(Dictionary<string, string> dictionary, string key)
        {
            if (dictionary == null) return "";
            string value;
            if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value)) return "";
            return value;
        }

        public Dictionary<string, string> getFormVariables(string body)
        {
            string[] variableAssignments = body.Split('&');
            Dictionary<string, string> formVariableDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (string variableAssignment in variableAssignments)
            {
                string[] parts = variableAssignment.Split('=');
                if (parts.Length == 2) formVariableDictionary.Add(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(parts[0]), HttpUtility.UrlDecode(parts[1]));
            }
            return formVariableDictionary;
        }
    }

}
```